# How to reuse class methods in typescript

Tags: typescript, oop, interface, prototype, composition

I know I can declare functions with a this interface using TS:

```
interface SayName {
  name: string;
  say(): string;
}

function say(this: SayName) {
  return this.name;
}
```

Then I wanted to use this function as class methods to classes that implements the SayName interface. I can do this, for example:

```
export class Hello implements SayName {
  name = "hello";
  say = say;
}
```

And the sayMethod will work just fine, but it won't be added to the prototype chain, so it won't be just the same as declaring a Method.

I could do this instead:

```
export class Hello implements SayName {
  name = "hello";
}
export interface Hello extends SayName {}
Hello.prototype.say = say;
```

And it also works, but I don't like this solution that much. Does Anyone have a better idea?

Comment: "but I don't like this solution that much" - why don't you like it?

Comment: When I do this, Typescript does not check if I really implemented the interface. It does not give me an error if I forget to add the method to the prototype. And it thinks that the method is at the surface of the object, so if a then copy the object like `{...new Hello()}`, typescript thinks that this method is on the copy (and it is not).

Answer (score 0):

What you are currently doing is a bad practice because you are misusing interfaces and `this`.

In essence, your code is roughly translated into this JavaScript:

```js
function say(){
  return this.name;
}

function Hello(){}
Hello.name = 'hello';
Hello.say = say;
```

See how `prototype` is not mentioned anywhere.

To make something appear in the prototype chain, it must be declared as class method, getter or setter.

Therefore, to do what you want to do, you can do something like this:

```
interface SayName {
  name: string;
  say(): string;
}

function say(this: SayName) {
  return this.name;
}

export class Hello implements SayName {
  name = "hello";
  get say(){
    return say;
  }
}
```

This is roughly translated into:

```js
function say(){
  return this.name;
}

function Hello(){}
Hello.name = 'hello';
Object.defineProperty(Hello.prototype, 'say', {
  configurable: true,
  enumerable: false,
  get: function(){
    return say;
  }
});
```

But then again, what you achieved here is most likely not actually what you expected because `this.name` in `function say()` will not be `'hello'`. You'll need to use [.bind](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind) for it, but that's out of scope for this question.

Comment: What I did at first was equivalent to this:
`function Hello(){
    this.name="hello"
    this.say=say
}`

Comment: The getter is not what I wanted, it will return the funcion every time it executes. I Just wanted to reuse the `say` method some way the it would be just the same as write it again.